# Win10 - Quarantined file by McAfee - r_74DB6FURNR2TGPBK.bin

Tags: windows-10, hexdump

On my Win10 desktop, McAfee quarantined the file, `r_74DB6FURNR2TGPBK.bin`, located at:

`C:\Users\UserAnon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\IdentityCache\1\UD\u_HJI7MQHTOTD91KRC\e_C2GK9UTC67FSUCG3\Accounts`

[Image of the File Explorer window containing the file, r_74DB6FURNR2TGPBK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcnIb.png)

Whatever created the file, created a new folder named, Accounts.  This is illustrated in this image:

[Image showing the new folder, Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rGNo.png)

McAfee was happy to delete the file but after some time the file reappeared.  I've been monitoring the file and have observed that the modified date/time keeps changing.

I had wondered if there was anything obvious in the file so I ran it through an online hex viewer.  I have attached an image of the partial output:

[Image of online hex editor browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9bge.png)

I've searched the registry for the filename - there wasn't any matches.  I've pointed McAfee directly at the file to scan and it says the file is ok.

I've Googled for the filename but there wasn't any returns.

Does the superuser brains trust have any ideas of what the purpose of this file is?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you happen to have Microsoft SQL Server installed?

Comment: @Ramhound: No, SQL is not installed.

Comment: Do you have any software installed that would use IdentityCache? The existence of a IdentityCache is legitimate.

Comment: Might it be Microsoft Teams (https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/Users-are-prompted-with-login-prompt-for-Microsoft-Teams?language=en_US) ? Also see https://download.mcafee.com/products/webhelp/4/1033/GUID-479F589F-DFB5-45B3-8306-6A9E5F2F9941.html to get more info on the file.